# Python regular expressions matching within set

Tags: python, regex

While testing on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ (online regex tester), the regex `[jpg|bmp]` returns results when either jpg or bmp exist, however, when I run this regex in python, it only return j or b. How do I make the regex take the whole word "jpg" or "bmp" inside the set ? This may have been asked before however I was not sure how to structure question to find the answer. Thanks !!!

Here is the whole regex if it helps

```
"http://www\S*(?i)\\.(jpg|bmp|png|gif|img|jng|jpeg|jpe|gif|giff)"
```

Its just basically to look for pictures in a url

Answer (score 5):

Use [`(jpg|bmp)`](http://regexr.com?2uf3s) instead of square brackets.

Square brackets mean - match a character from the set in the square brackets.

Edit - you might want something like that: [`[^ ].*?(jpg|bmp)`](http://regexr.com?2uf3v) or `[^ ].*?\.(jpg|bmp)`

Comment: Tried that, now it only returns the file extension, not the first part of the url

Comment: Then you should rephrase your question.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, still returns only jpg, forgets about preceding matched characters

Comment: Did you try wrapping it wrap it with parenthesis?

Answer (score 3):

When you are using `[]` your are creating a character class that contains all characters between the brackets.

So your are not matching for `jpg` or `bmp` you are matching for either a `j` or a `p` or a `g` or a `|` ...

You should add an anchor for the end of the string to your regex

```
http://www\S*(?i)\\.(jpg|bmp|png|gif|img|jng|jpeg|jpe|gif|giff)$
          ^      ^^
```

if you need double escaping then every where in your pattern

```
http://www\\S*(?i)\\.(jpg|bmp|png|gif|img|jng|jpeg|jpe|gif|giff)$
```

to ensure that it checks for the file ending at the very end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching a list of URLs

```
urls = [ 'http://some.link.com/path/to/file.jpg',
         'http://some.link.com/path/to/another.png',
         'http://and.another.place.com/path/to/not-image.txt',
       ]
```

to find ones that match a given pattern you can use:

```
import re
for url in urls:
   if re.match(r'http://.*(jpg|png|gif)$'):
      print url
```

which will output

```
http://some.link.com/path/to/file.jpg
http://some.link.com/path/to/another.png
```

`re.match()` will test for a match at the start of the string and return a *match object* for the first two links, and `None` for the third.

If you are getting just the extension, you can use the following:

```
for url in urls:
   m = re.match(r'http://.*(jpg|png|gif)$')
   print m.group(0)
```

which will print

```
('jpg',)
('png',)
```

You will get just the extensions because that's what was defined as a group.

If you need to find the url in a long string of text (such as returned from wget), you need to use `re.search()` and enclose the part you are interested in with `( )`'s. For example,

```
response = """dlkjkd dkjfadlfjkd fkdfl kadfjlkadfald ljkdskdfkl adfdf
    kjakldjflkhttp://some.url.com/path/to/file.jpgkaksdj fkdjakjflakdjfad;kadj af
    kdlfjd dkkf aldfkaklfakldfkja df"""

reg = re.search(r'(http:.*/(.*\.(jpg|png|gif)))', response)

print reg.groups()
```

will print

```
('http://some.url.com/path/to/file.jpg', 'file.jpg', 'jpg',)
```

or you can use `re.findall` or `re.finditer` in place of `re.search` to get all of the URL's in the long response. Search will only return the first one.

Comment: You're missing the second argument to "match" everywhere.